# localizedNameOfStringEncoding doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, string, nsstring

```
const NSStringEncoding *enc = [NSString availableStringEncodings];
while (*enc != 0) {
    NSString *name = [NSString localizedNameOfStringEncoding:*enc];
    NSLog(@"%@ %d",name, *enc);
    enc++;
}
```

Name is empty, and I'm using IOS 6, is this a bug? Or did I do anything wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: File a bug. http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your code to have

```
NSLog(@"%@ %d (0x%x)",name, *enc, *enc);
```

so we can see the NSStringEncoding in hex as well as decimal. Running you test code on the iOS 6.1 iPhone simulator I get a total of 88 different NSStringEncodings, some of which return a meaningful localizedNameOfStringEncoding, these being:

```
Unicode (UTF-16) 10 (0xa)
Unicode (UTF-7) -2080374528 (0x84000100)
Unicode (UTF-8) 4 (0x4)
Unicode (UTF-32) -1946156800 (0x8c000100)
Unicode (UTF-16BE) -1879047936 (0x90000100)
Unicode (UTF-16LE) -1811939072 (0x94000100)
Unicode (UTF-32BE) -1744830208 (0x98000100)
Unicode (UTF-32LE) -1677721344 (0x9c000100)
Non-lossy ASCII 7 (0x7)
```

Presumably there just *aren't* localized names for all the myriad of supported encodings.